# Cannot Get My Data From MySQL Android Volley Response

Tags: php, android, mysql, android-volley

Can you help me with this one, I'm stuck with the login part. I can successfully register but failed to logged in.

**Login.java**

```
//LOGIN VOLLEY REQUEST
public void loginUser(){
    final String userEmail = editTextEmailAddress.getText().toString().toLowerCase().trim();
    final String userPass = editTextPassword.getText().toString().trim();

    //RESPONSE TRUE
    Response.Listener<String> listener = new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
                //JSON RESPONSE
                try {
                    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                    boolean recordFound = jsonObject.getBoolean("success");

                    if (recordFound) {
                        //GET RESPONSE FROM SERVER STORED TEMPORARILY, THEN TO SHARED PREFERENCE
                        //SAME ORDER AS WITH THE PHP CODE SEQUENCE
                        String uniqueId = jsonObject.getString("uniqueID");
                        String userType = jsonObject.getString("userType");
                        String firstName = jsonObject.getString("FirstName");
                        String lastName = jsonObject.getString("LastName");
                        String birthDate = jsonObject.getString("Birthdate");
                        String gender = jsonObject.getString("Gender");
                        String occupation = jsonObject.getString("Occupation");
                        String dateJoined = jsonObject.getString("DateRegister");
                        String orgJoined = jsonObject.getString("UserOrgJoined");
                        String friends = jsonObject.getString("UserFriends");
                        String volunteer = jsonObject.getString("volunteeredTotal");

                        //STORE THE CURRENT USER LOGGED IN BEFORE GO TO MAIN- SESSION START
                        SharedPreferences userSharedPreference = LoginActivity.this.getSharedPreferences(UserSharedPreference.SHARED_PREFERENCES_HOLDER, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                        SharedPreferences.Editor spEditor = userSharedPreference.edit();
                        spEditor.putBoolean(ServerScripts.LOGIN_RESPONSE, true);

                        //GET DATA FROM THE SERVER DATABASE AND SAVE TO PREFERENCE
                        spEditor.putString(UserSharedPreference.EMAIL_ADDRESS, userEmail);
                        spEditor.putString(UserSharedPreference.KEY_USERNAME_EMAIL_ADDRESS, userEmail);
                        spEditor.putString(UserSharedPreference.USER_UNIQUE_ID, uniqueId);
                        spEditor.putString(UserSharedPreference.FIRST_NAME, firstName);
                        spEditor.putString(UserSharedPreference.LAST_NAME, lastName);
                        spEditor.putString(UserSharedPreference.GENDER, gender);
                        spEditor.putString(UserSharedPreference.BIRTH_DATE, birthDate);
                        spEditor.putString(UserSharedPreference.OCCUPATION, occupation);
                        spEditor.putString(UserSharedPreference.USER_JOINED_DATE, dateJoined);
                        spEditor.putString(UserSharedPreference.USER_TYPE, userType);
                        spEditor.putString(UserSharedPreference.USER_UNIQUE_ID, uniqueId);
                        spEditor.putString(UserSharedPreference.COMMUNITY_FRIENDS, friends);
                        spEditor.putString(UserSharedPreference.ORGANIZATION_JOINED, orgJoined);
                        spEditor.putString(UserSharedPreference.VOLUNTEERED, volunteer);


                        spEditor.apply();
                        progressDialogLogin.dismiss();

                        Intent intentStartMainActivity = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                        intentStartMainActivity.putExtra("emailAddress", UserSharedPreference.EMAIL_ADDRESS);
                        intentStartMainActivity.putExtra("firstName", UserSharedPreference.FIRST_NAME);
                        intentStartMainActivity.putExtra("lastName", UserSharedPreference.LAST_NAME);
                        startActivity(intentStartMainActivity);
                        finish();
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.getStackTrace();
                    //Log.i("","Get");
                }

        }
    };
    //RESPONSE FALSE
    Response.ErrorListener errorListener = new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            String failed = error + "";
            if (failed.equalsIgnoreCase("failed")) {
                AlertDialog.Builder response = new AlertDialog.Builder(LoginActivity.this);
                response.setTitle(R.string.error)
                        .setMessage(R.string.somethingWentWrong)
                        .setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                //DO NOTHING
                            }
                        })
                        .create()
                        .show();
            }
        }
    };

    LoginRequestVolley loginRequestVolley = new LoginRequestVolley(userEmail,userPass,listener,errorListener);
    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(LoginActivity.this);
    requestQueue.add(loginRequestVolley);
    progressDialogLogin = new ProgressDialog(this);
    progressDialogLogin.setTitle("Connecting To Server");
    progressDialogLogin.setMessage("This may take a few seconds. Retrieving Data...");
    progressDialogLogin.getProgress();
    progressDialogLogin.show();
}
```

**LoginVolley.java**

```
public class LoginRequestVolley extends StringRequest {
private static final String KEY_EMAIL = "emailAddress";
private static final String KEY_PASSWORD = "password";

private Map<String, String> params;

//FOR LOGIN VOLLEY
public LoginRequestVolley(String emailAddress, String password,
                          Response.Listener<String> listener, Response.ErrorListener errorListener){
    super(Method.POST, ServerScripts.PHP_SCRIPT_PATH + ServerScripts.PHP_LOGIN, listener, errorListener);
    params = new HashMap<>();
    params.put(KEY_EMAIL,emailAddress);
    params.put(KEY_PASSWORD,password);
}}
```

PHP - Log in **userLogin.php**

```
<?php

 if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){
 //ASSIGN TO VARIABLES - HOLDERS
    $userEmail = $_POST['emailAddress'];
    $userPass = $_POST['password'];

    require('dbConnect.php');
      //SQLI STATEMENT - GET SPECIFIC DATA     
    $SQLi_LOGIN = "SELECT uniqueID, userType, FirstName, LastName, Gender,
                          Birthday, Occupation, EmailAddress, Password ,DateRegister,
                          UserOrgJoined, UserFriends, volunteeredTotal 
                          FROM useryayong WHERE 
                          EmailAddress = ? AND Password = ?";

    $statement = mysqli_prepare($dbConnect,$SQLi_LOGIN);  
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, "ss", $userEmail,$userPass); 
    mysqli_stmt_execute($statement) or die("Error:".mysqli_error($dbConnect));                     
    mysqli_stmt_store_result($results = $statement);  
    mysqli_stmt_bind_result($statement, $colUniqueId, $colUserType, $colFirstName,$colLastName,
                            $colGender, $colBirthday,$colOccupation,$colEmail, $colPassword,
                            $colDateRegister,$colUserOrgJoined,$colUserFriends,
                            $colVolunteer);


    //$recordSearch = mysqli_query($dbConnect, $SQLi_LOGIN) or die("Error".mysqli_error($dbConnect));


        $recordFound = array();
        $recordFound["success"] = false;  

   while(mysqli_stmt_fetch($results)){                
        $recordFound["success"] = true;  
        $recordFound = $_POST["uniqueID"] = $colUniqueId;
        $recordFound = $_POST["userDefaultType"] = $colUserType;
        $recordFound = $_POST["userFirstName"] = $colFirstName;
        $recordFound = $_POST["userLastName"] = $colLastName;
        $recordFound = $_POST["userGender"] = $colGender;
        $recordFound = $_POST["userBirthdate"] = $colBirthday;
        $recordFound = $_POST["userOccupation"] = $colOccupation;
        $recordFound = $_POST["userDateRegister"] = $colDateRegister;
        $recordFound = $_POST["UserOrgNoJoined"] = $colUserOrgJoined;
        $recordFound = $_POST["UserNoFriends"] = $colUserFriends;
        $recordFound = $_POST["volunteeredTotalNo"] = $colVolunteer;
     }
        echo json_encode($recordFound);}
```

I got into debugging mode and trace it, I got this results
[image: Debug]

[image: step to]

The error is in the php code. The response.

Comment: put debug point in onResponse & onErrorResponse method. debug code

Comment: I always get mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1

Comment: check this http://forums.phpfreaks.com/topic/129396-solved-why-warning-mysqli-fetch-array-expects-parameter-1-to-be-mysqli-result/

Comment: Try to use maybe postman to check where server output is as your expected

Comment: How do I use this post man? I used method PoST for this one.

Answer (score 0):

```
//LOGIN VOLLEY REQUEST
public void loginUser(){
final String userEmail =    editTextEmailAddress.getText().toString().toLowerCase().trim();
final String userPass = editTextPassword.getText().toString().trim();

//RESPONSE TRUE
Response.Listener<String> listener = new Response.Listener<String>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(String response) {
            //JSON RESPONSE
            try {
                JSONArray array = response.getJSONArray("your_array");
                JSONObject jsonObject = array.getJSONObject(0);

                if (recordFound) {
                    //GET RESPONSE FROM SERVER STORED TEMPORARILY, THEN TO SHARED PREFERENCE
                    //SAME ORDER AS WITH THE PHP CODE SEQUENCE
                    String uniqueId = jsonObject.getString("uniqueID");
                    String userType = jsonObject.getString("userType");
                    String firstName = jsonObject.getString("FirstName");
                    String lastName = jsonObject.getString("LastName");
                    String birthDate = jsonObject.getString("Birthdate");
                    String gender = jsonObject.getString("Gender");
                    String occupation = jsonObject.getString("Occupation");
                    String dateJoined = jsonObject.getString("DateRegister");
                    String orgJoined = jsonObject.getString("UserOrgJoined");
                    String friends = jsonObject.getString("UserFriends");
                    String volunteer = jsonObject.getString("volunteeredTotal");

                    //STORE THE CURRENT USER LOGGED IN BEFORE GO TO MAIN- SESSION START
                    SharedPreferences userSharedPreference = LoginActivity.this.getSharedPreferences(UserSharedPreference.SHARED_PREFERENCES_HOLDER, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                    SharedPreferences.Editor spEditor = userSharedPreference.edit();
                    spEditor.putBoolean(ServerScripts.LOGIN_RESPONSE, true);

                    //GET DATA FROM THE SERVER DATABASE AND SAVE TO PREFERENCE
                    spEditor.putString(UserSharedPreference.EMAIL_ADDRESS, userEmail);
                    spEditor.putString(UserSharedPreference.KEY_USERNAME_EMAIL_ADDRESS, userEmail);
                    spEditor.putString(UserSharedPreference.USER_UNIQUE_ID, uniqueId);
                    spEditor.putString(UserSharedPreference.FIRST_NAME, firstName);
                    spEditor.putString(UserSharedPreference.LAST_NAME, lastName);
                    spEditor.putString(UserSharedPreference.GENDER, gender);
                    spEditor.putString(UserSharedPreference.BIRTH_DATE, birthDate);
                    spEditor.putString(UserSharedPreference.OCCUPATION, occupation);
                    spEditor.putString(UserSharedPreference.USER_JOINED_DATE, dateJoined);
                    spEditor.putString(UserSharedPreference.USER_TYPE, userType);
                    spEditor.putString(UserSharedPreference.USER_UNIQUE_ID, uniqueId);
                    spEditor.putString(UserSharedPreference.COMMUNITY_FRIENDS, friends);
                    spEditor.putString(UserSharedPreference.ORGANIZATION_JOINED, orgJoined);
                    spEditor.putString(UserSharedPreference.VOLUNTEERED, volunteer);


                    spEditor.apply();
                    progressDialogLogin.dismiss();

                    Intent intentStartMainActivity = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                    intentStartMainActivity.putExtra("emailAddress", UserSharedPreference.EMAIL_ADDRESS);
                    intentStartMainActivity.putExtra("firstName", UserSharedPreference.FIRST_NAME);
                    intentStartMainActivity.putExtra("lastName", UserSharedPreference.LAST_NAME);
                    startActivity(intentStartMainActivity);
                    finish();
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.getStackTrace();
                //Log.i("","Get");
            }

    }
};
//RESPONSE FALSE
Response.ErrorListener errorListener = new Response.ErrorListener() {
    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        String failed = error + "";
        if (failed.equalsIgnoreCase("failed")) {
            AlertDialog.Builder response = new AlertDialog.Builder(LoginActivity.this);
            response.setTitle(R.string.error)
                    .setMessage(R.string.somethingWentWrong)
                    .setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            //DO NOTHING
                        }
                    })
                    .create()
                    .show();
        }
    }
};

LoginRequestVolley loginRequestVolley = new LoginRequestVolley(userEmail,userPass,listener,errorListener);
RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(LoginActivity.this);
requestQueue.add(loginRequestVolley);
progressDialogLogin = new ProgressDialog(this);
progressDialogLogin.setTitle("Connecting To Server");
progressDialogLogin.setMessage("This may take a few seconds. Retrieving Data...");
progressDialogLogin.getProgress();
progressDialogLogin.show();
}
```